# No Path Generated by Path Planner

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I  followed the navigation stack tutorial succesfully until the part when I try to issue a goal to the stack via RVIZ. If i click on set goal, the goal is set, because when suscribed to the goal topic i can see the arrow representing the goal. The problem is that no path gets planned and no error message is sent by the move_base node.

Any ideas?

Im running Diamondback on ubuntu 10.10 intalled via apt-get. The PC has an i7 and 4 gigs ram.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9811/no-path-generated-by-path-planner/) by [Pablo Hevia-Koch](https://answers.ros.org/users/299/pablo-hevia-koch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps a silly question, but is the goal topic published by rviz mapped to the correct goal topic to which your nav stack is subscribed to? (in rviz the goal topic is found in the right hand panel)

do a '`rostopic list`' to see if you have a mismatch. That got me once.

mine is something like `move_base_simple/goal`

PS. also check `rxconsole` to see if anything nasty is happening

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Hevia-Koch](https://answers.ros.org/users/299/pablo-hevia-koch/) on 2011-04-25**:
Actually, it was that. I feel kind of ashamed of not noticing, but I mixed up the "move_base/goal" with the "move_base_simple/goal". Now i have a different problem, the local planner doesn't quite follow the global plan, but i guess ill have to make another question about that.